# Is it safe/wise to run Drupal alongside bespoke business web apps in production?

Tags: sql, drupal, iis, production-environment

I'm interested to know the general community feeling about the safety of running Drupal alongside bespoke, business critial ASP.NET MVC apps on a production server.

Previously my employer's Drupal based 'visitor website' was hosted as a managed service with a 3rd party. While the LoB sites were hosted in-house. That 3rd party is no longer available so I'm considering my options:

1. Bring Drupal in-house
2. Find another 3rd party

My concern is that I have little experience with Drupal administration (and no experience securing it) and that the addition of PHP to my IIS server poses a security risk.

Is there a best practice that I can follow in this situation?

Comment: This question belongs on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Thanks. I'm a bit new to StackExchange. I've moved my question.

Answer (score 0):

Vortexfive is right. This is more of a sysadmin question.

Now at https://serverfault.com/questions/446366/is-it-safe-wise-to-run-drupal-alongside-bespoke-business-web-apps-in-production